# How to override MaintenanceMode.php in magento 2 in my custom module?

Tags: magento2, maintenance

How to override MaintenanceMode.php in magento 2 in my custom module?

> /vendor/magento/framework/App/MaintenanceMode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create di.xml in your module then use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference 
        for="Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode" 
        type="VENDOR\MODULE\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode" 
        />
</config>
```